# How to say a given vector field is inward, outward or tengent to a hypersurface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

For given a hypersurface $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a vector field v on $\mathbb{R}^n$, is there any standard way to determine the vector field v is inward or outward or tangent to $S$?

In general given two manifolds $M^m$ and $N^n$ such that $M^m\subset N^n$, and a vector field v in $N^n$, can we say the vector field v is inward or outward or tangent to $M$?

Thanks, advance.

Comment: Taking the dot product with outward pointing normal vector is quite standard.

Comment: Whats your definition of inward and outward ?

Comment: Using the orientations of hypersurface and $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: You need to specify an orientation (i.e., an outward-pointing normal vector field) for the hypersurface. For $m<n-1$, there is no notion of "inward" or "outward"; think about $M$ as a line in $N=\Bbb R^3$. It doesn't divide space into an "inside" and an "outside."